# Global variable value not persisting on page postback in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, pageload, page-lifecycle

I'am implementing a quiz portal type web application.

First question is fetching fine from db.
clicking on next button,next question is fetching fine. Now again clicking on **next or prev** button nothing happens!

**Concept used** - made a global variable which will be equal to the current question no. from my questions table, incrementing/decrementing variable on next/prev clicks

why this approach is not working!
what code should i change in Page_Load or else where?

**note:**

1.disconnected model used

2.countdown timer is working fine on postbacks,no issue.

**Attached images**..

1.[question table design here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZm2G.png)

2.On default page(ques1) and on clicking next button(ques2) 
 [Q1. and Q2. combined image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ftvs5.png)

```
public partial class quiz : System.Web.UI.Page
{
int qno=0;  //global variable
DataTable dt;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (Session["sname"] == null)
    {
        Response.Redirect("home.aspx");
    }
    string qpname = Request.QueryString["qpname"]; //question paper table name

    //**some countdown timer code here**

    SqlConnection conn = null;
    conn = new SqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=xyz; Initial Catalog=xzyyzz;Integrated Security=True;";

     String queryString = "select * from " + qpname + "";
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryString, conn);      
     SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, conn);
     dt = new DataTable();
     ad.Fill(dt);


     foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
      {
          Label6.Text = row["marks"].ToString(); //for marks of current ques. 
          Label7.Text = row["ques"].ToString();  //for ques.
          qno = (int)row["qno"]; //ques no.
          qno = qno + 1; //
          break;
       }

}


protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //some timer code here
}

public class CountDownTimer
{
   //some timer code here
}

protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Response.Redirect("student.aspx"); //redirect on submit

}

protected void prev_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   //prev button
{

    display_ques(-1);

}
protected void next_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   //next button
{
    display_ques(1);
}

public void display_ques(int direction)
{
    DataRow[] result = dt.Select(" qno = " +qno+ ""); //for current ques no.

    foreach (DataRow row in result)
    {
        Label6.Text = row["marks"].ToString();
        Label7.Text = row["ques"].ToString();
        if (direction == 1)
            qno=qno+1;
        else
            qno=qno-1;
        break;

    }
}
}
```

please help guys! stuck on this..

Comment: Check my answer and tell me if helped you

Answer (score 1):

If you want to persist some value between postbacks use `Session` or `ViewState`.

```
Session["qno"] = (int)row["qno"];
```

How to take the the value from Session.

```
int qno = 0;
if(Session["qno"] != null)
   qno = int.TryParse(Session["qno"].ToString(), out qno);
```